# Attack Titan holders

Tags: attack-on-titan

If Eren was the one who instigated Grisha to retake the Founding Titan then why was he shocked to learn that his father slaughtered the Reiss family in season 3 ?
Moreover  Eren didn't have the abilities of Attack Titan  when Grisha did this . So does the Attack Titan have the ability to peek into future and past memories of other Attack Titan holders even when it isn't possessed by its destined holder ( here Eren ) ?

Answer (score 2):

I am not completely sure, as I have not read the manga but from watching the anime, people who have the titan power inherit the memories of their predecessors. I think they only have the memories of their immediate predecessor, as they never showed Eren to look back past Grisha's memories. When Grisha had slaughtered the Reiss family, Eren was not born. However, he inherited all of Grisha's memories because Eren got the Attack Titan from Grisha. When Eren was having flashbacks of Grisha's memories, he had no clue about why Grisha was doing this. He had not been to the basement under their house with all the information yet. So to him, he saw his father murdering a whole family with unclear intent.

Answer (score 0):

The Attack titan makes it so that the owner can see thru the future owner's eyes, not teleport there.

I think that in s3, when Eren saw Grisha's memories he only saw the part when he killed the Reiss family, not the part where he moarned their death and regretted everything. Plus, I'm pretty sure Eren's flashbacks are limited, so he cannot see everything because he does not have royal blood